# iOS Navigation Items - toggle programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS (swift) programming. I am creating my first stop watch application. I have added a `navigationBar` to the `MainStoryBoard`, and then two navigation items on the bar, one on the left and one on the right. I would like to change the text of left navigation item in the `viewDidLoad` method and then in an `IBAction`. Can anyone help me please.

With my .NET coding intellect, I created `IBOutlets` for each of them and then tried changing their title properties but have failed.

Another similar question regarding the same is how can I toggle the icons on navigation items programmatically.

Comment: Can you add some code

Answer (score 2):

For `UIBarButtonItem` with custom button image:

```
let btnName = UIButton()

btnName.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), forState: .Normal)

btnName.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)

btnName.addTarget(self, action: Selector("action"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Set Right/Left Bar Button item:

```
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()

rightBarButton.customView = btnName

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

For System `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
let camera = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Camera, target: self, action: Selector("btnOpenCamera"))

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = camera
```

Answer (score 2):

You should don't create `UINavigationBar` on `StoryBoard`. You should ember it into `UINavigationController`. And in `viewDidLoad` you can add `NavigationItem` programmatically.

Add `NavigationBarItem` just with text:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "left", style: .Done, target: self, action: "leftTap")
```

With Image:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backIcon@3x"), style: .Done, target: self, action: "rightTap")
```

And in `Action` you can change text or image:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = "left change"
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.image = UIImage(named: "calendar-icons@3x")
```

With title and image above just is demo. You can reference to my demo code: [Demo Change NavigationItem Programmatically](https://github.com/vienvu89/DemoNavigationButton)

Hop this help!